# How can I make this code less verbose?

Tags: python

I am making a simple 'guess a number between one and ten' game. I have used some basic error handling and am printing the number generated by the random module for testing purposes.

However I would like to know if there is a less verbose way to write this.

This is the code:

```
import random

while True:

    """Variable declaration"""
    number_of_attempts = 1
    number = random.randrange (1,11)
    print (number)
    print("Time to play a guessing game! Muhahaha...")


    """Error handling and main game code/while loop"""

    while True:

        try:
            guess = int(input("Guess a number between one and ten."))

        except ValueError:
            print("Input a whole number between one and ten silly!")
            continue

        if guess >= 1 and guess <= 10:
            pass
        else:
            print("Input a number between one and ten silly!")
            continue   

        if guess == number:
            print("You were successful and it took you", number_of_attempts, "attempts!!!")
            break

        else:
            print("Try again!")   
            number_of_attempts = number_of_attempts +1

    """Game Exit/Restart"""

    play_again = input("Would you like to play again, y/n?")

    if "y" in play_again or "yes" in play_again:
        continue

    else:
        break
```

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: You have way too many useless `pass`, `continue` and `break` statements. Also `if "y" in play_again or "yes" in play_again:` is exactly equivalent to `if 'y' in play_again`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if guess >= 1 and guess <= 10:
```

Can be written as:

```
if 1 <= guess <= 10:
```

Also, your first conditional can simply be written as:

```
if not 1 <= guess <= 10:
    print("Input a number between one and ten silly!")
    continue
```

But this can also be put inside the `try` bit, saving you from writing `continue` twice:

```
try:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between one and ten."))
    if not 1 <= guess <= 10:
        print("Input a number between one and ten silly!")
        continue
except ValueError:
    print("Input a whole number between one and ten silly!")
    continue
```

Finally your last conditional can simply be:

```
if play_again not in ('y', 'yes'):
    break
```

The `continue` isn't needed.

You may also want to wrap this all up into a function as well, to get rid of those infinite while loops and to prevent you from using `continue` and `break` so much.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the actual conditions on the while loops so you don't have to hunt for breaks to understand the loops?  It would make your code clearer and smaller.

```
 if guess == number:
        print("You were successful and it took you", number_of_attempts, "attempts!!!")
        break
```

For instance if you put guess == number as the while loop conditional then the print would be the first thing after the loop. Initialize guess to -1 so it always works the first time.  The play again if statement could also disappear into the loop conditional as well.